# symfony 2 & sonata admin debug toolbar broken, failed, and display blank

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, toolbar, sonata

Sometimes I click the (symfony2 & the back-end I use sonata admin) debug toolbar button it display blank:
[display nothing(check the image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0HII.png)

Here is source of Firefox , it's broken here(in a svg tag):

```
</div>
```

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="header" class="clear-fix">
<h1>
    <svg width="275" height="62" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 275 62" enable-background="new 0 0 275 62" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#010202" d="M31 0C13.9 0 0 13.9 0 31c0 17.1 13.9 31 31 31c17.1 0 31-13.9 31-31C62 13.9 48.1 0 31 0z M47.7 17.9 c-1.4 0-2.4-0.8-2.5-2.1c0-0.5 0.1-0.9 0.4-1.4c0.3-0.6 0.4-0.7 0.4-1c0-0.8-1.3-0.9-1.6-0.8c-4.7 0.2-5.9 6.4-6.9 11.5l-0.5 2.7 c2.7 0.4 4.6-0.1 5.6-0.8c1.5-1-0.4-2-0.2-3.1c0.2-1.1 1.3-1.7 2.1-1.7c1.1 0 2 1.2 1.9 2.3c0 2-2.7 4.7-7.9 4.6 c-0.6 0-1.2-0.1-1.8-0.1l-1 5.5c-0.9 4.1-2.1 9.8-6.3 14.7c-3.6 4.3-7.3 5-8.9 5c-3.1 0.1-5.1-1.5-5.2-3.7c-0.1-2.1 1.8-3.3 3-3.3 c1.6-0.1 2.8 1.1 2.8 2.5c0 1.2-0.6 1.5-1 1.7c-0.3 0.2-0.7 0.4-0.7 0.9c0 0.2 0.2 0.7 0.9 0.7c1.3 0 2.2-0.7 2.8-1.1 c3-2.5 4.2-6.9 5.7-14.8l0.3-1.9c0.5-2.6 1.1-5.5 2-8.3c-2.1-1.6-3.4-3.6-6.2-4.3c-1.9-0.5-3.1-0.1-4 1c-1 1.3-0.7 2.9 0.3 3.8 l1.6 1.7c1.9 2.2 3 4 2.6 6.3c-0.6 3.7-5.1 6.6-10.4 5c-4.5-1.4-5.3-4.6-4.8-6.3c0.5-1.5 1.7-1.8 2.9-1.5c1.3 0.4 1.8 2 1.4 3.2 c0 0.1-0.1 0.3-0.2 0.6c-0.1 0.3-0.4 0.6-0.5 1c-0.3 0.9 1 1.6 1.9 1.9c2 0.6 4-0.4 4.5-2.1c0.5-1.5-0.5-2.5-0.9-2.9l-1.9-2 c-0.9-1-2.8-3.7-1.9-6.7c0.4-1.2 1.1-2.4 2.2-3.2c2.3-1.7 4.9-2 7.3-1.3c3.1 0.9 4.6 3 6.6 4.6c1.1-3.2 2.6-6.3 4.9-8.9 c2-2.4 4.8-4.1 7.9-4.2c3.1-0.1 5.5 1.3 5.6 3.6C50.2 16 49.6 17.9 47.7 17.9z"/><g><g><path fill="#010202" d="M142.8 25c4.5 0 7.5 3.3 7.5 7.8c0 4.2-3.1 7.8-7.5 7.8c-4.5 0-7.6-3.5-7.6-7.8 C135.2 28.3 138.2 25 142.8 25z M142.8 38.3c3.2 0 4.6-2.9 4.6-5.6c0-2.8-1.7-5.6-4.6-5.6c-2.9 0-4.7 2.7-4.7 5.6 C138.1 35.4 139.6 38.3 142.8 38.3z"/></g><path fill="#010202" d="M134.8 26.4v-1h-3.9v-1.4c0-2 0.3-3.5 2.6-3.5c0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0c0 0 0 0 0 0c0.7 0 1.2-0.5 1.2-1.1l0-0.9 c-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.2-1.8-0.2c-4 0-5 2.4-5 6v1.2h-3.5v1.2c0.1 0.6 0.6 1.1 1.2 1.1c0 0 0 0 0 0h2.3v12.6h1.5c0 0 0 0 0 0 c0.6 0 1.1-0.5 1.2-1.1V27.6h2.7C134.3 27.5 134.8 27 134.8 26.4z"/><path fill="#010202" d="M98.4 25.4C98.4 25.4 98.4 25.4 98.4 25.4c-0.6 0-1.1 0.4-1.4 0.9l-3.8 11.3h-0.1l-3.7-11.3 c-0.2-0.5-0.8-0.9-1.4-0.9c0 0 0 0 0 0h-1.9l5 13.8c0.2 0.5 0.5 1.3 0.5 1.6c0 0.3-0.8 3.7-3.3 3.7c-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0 c-0.6 0-1.1 0.4-1.2 1.1l-0.1 0.9c0.5 0.1 1 0.2 1.9 0.2c3.6 0 4.7-3.3 5.7-6.1l5.5-15.2L98.4 25.4L98.4 25.4z"/><path fill="#010202" d="M81.1 28.4c-2.3-1.2-4.7-1.9-4.8-4.3c0-2.5 2.3-3.1 4-3.1c0 0 0 0 0 0c0.8 0 1.4 0.1 2 0.2c0 0 0 0 0 0 c0.6 0 1.2-0.4 1.2-1.1l0-0.9c-1.1-0.3-2.3-0.4-3.4-0.4c-3.8 0-6.6 1.9-6.6 5.6c0 3.2 2.2 4.4 4.5 5.5c2.3 1.1 4.8 2 4.8 4.6 c0 2.7-2.7 3.8-4.5 3.8c-1.1 0-2.2-0.3-3.2-0.6c-0.6-0.1-1.1 0.4-1.2 1.2l-0.1 0.8c1.3 0.4 2.7 0.8 4.1 0.8c0 0 0 0 0 0 c0 0 0 0 0 0c4.3 0 7.6-1.7 7.6-6.1C85.5 31 83.4 29.5 81.1 28.4z"/><path fill="#010202" d="M122.4 40.2C122.4 40.2 122.4 40.2 122.4 40.2c0.6 0 1.1-0.4 1.2-1v-8.5c0-3.2-1.4-5.7-5.1-5.7 c-1.3 0-3.6 0.8-4.6 2.9c-0.8-2-2.5-2.9-4.2-2.9c-2.2 0-3.7 0.8-4.7 2.5h-0.1v-0.9c0-0.7-0.6-1.2-1.2-1.2c0 0 0 0 0 0h-1.3v14.8 h1.5c0 0 0 0 0 0c0.7 0 1.2-0.6 1.2-1.2c0 0 0 0 0 0v-6.2c0-2.8 1.1-5.5 3.9-5.5c2.2 0 2.6 2.3 2.6 4.1v8.8h1.5c0 0 0 0 0 0 c0.6 0 1.2-0.5 1.2-1.1v-6.3c0-2.8 1.1-5.5 3.9-5.5c2.2 0 2.6 2.3 2.6 4.1v8.8L122.4 40.2L122.4 40.2z"/><path fill="#010202" d="M164.7 40.2C164.7 40.2 164.7 40.2 164.7 40.2c0.7 0 1.2-0.5 1.2-1.2v-7.6c0-4-1.7-6.4-5.6-6.4 c-2.1 0-4 1-4.9 2.7h-0.1v-1.1c0 0 0 0 0 0c0-0.7-0.6-1.2-1.2-1.2c0 0 0 0 0 0h-1.4v14.8h1.5c0 0 0 0 0 0c0.6 0 1.2-0.5 1.2-1.1 v-5.7c0-3.6 1.4-6.1 4.5-6.1c2.4 0.1 3.1 1.8 3.1 5.3v7.7L164.7 40.2L164.7 40.2z"/><path fill="#010202" d="M179.4 25.4C179.4 25.4 179.4 25.4 179.4 25.4c-0.6 0-1.1 0.4-1.4 0.9l-3.8 11.3h-0.1l-3.7-11.3 c-0.2-0.5-0.8-0.9-1.4-0.9c0 0 0 0 0 0h-1.9l5 13.8c0.2 0.5 0.5 1.3 0.5 1.6c0 0.3-0.8 3.7-3.3 3.7c-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0 c-0.6 0-1.1 0.4-1.2 1.1l-0.1 0.9c0.5 0.1 1 0.2 1.9 0.2c3.6 0 4.7-3.3 5.7-6.1l5.5-15.2L179.4 25.4L179.4 25.4z"/></g><g><path fill="#ADADAD" d="M185.7 46.4V25.1h2.4v2c0.6-0.8 1.2-1.4 1.9-1.8c0.7-0.4 1.6-0.6 2.6-0.6c1.3 0 2.5 0.3 3.5 1 c1 0.7 1.8 1.6 2.3 2.9c0.5 1.2 0.8 2.6 0.8 4.1c0 1.6-0.3 3-0.8 4.3c-0.6 1.3-1.4 2.2-2.5 2.9c-1.1 0.7-2.2 1-3.4 1 c-0.9 0-1.7-0.2-2.3-0.6c-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.8-1.7-1.4v7.5H185.7z M188.1 32.8c0 2 0.4 3.4 1.2 4.4s1.8 1.4 2.9 1.4 c1.2 0 2.2-0.5 3-1.5c0.8-1 1.2-2.5 1.2-4.6c0-2-0.4-3.4-1.2-4.4c-0.8-1-1.8-1.5-2.9-1.5c-1.1 0-2.1 0.5-3 1.6 C188.5 29.4 188.1 30.9 188.1 32.8z"/><path fill="#ADADAD" d="M202.2 40.5V25.1h2.4v2.3c0.6-1.1 1.2-1.8 1.7-2.2c0.5-0.3 1.1-0.5 1.7-0.5c0.9 0 1.8 0.3 2.7 0.8l-0.9 2.4 c-0.6-0.4-1.3-0.6-1.9-0.6c-0.6 0-1.1 0.2-1.5 0.5c-0.5 0.3
```

[In a svg tag(check the image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9h9C.png)

It's make me confused for a long time. Who can tell me why?

Comment: Do you see something about this in your application's log?

Comment: I have seen the log. But I didn't found any problem. I found some "request.INFO" and "event.DEBUG" logs, haven't found any error log .